# Can I write this in more idiomatic Active Record way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I rewrite this piece of code to use maximum of the Active Record Query interface and minimum SQL? Is there more idiomatic way to write it?

```
ticket_gifts = Gift
  .joins("LEFT JOIN giftable_items ON gifts.giftable_item_id = giftable_items.id")
  .select("gifts.total_value, gifts.created_at, gifts.user_id")
  .where("giftable_items.gift_type = 'ticket'")
  .to_sql
```

It's doing its job, but I'm not satisfied with that how it looks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
Gift.joins(:giftable_item).where(giftable_items: { gift_type: 'ticket' })
```

Depending on what is the relation between Gift & GiftableItem, if it is a has_many, use the pluralized version in the joins:

```
Gift.joins(:giftable_items).where(giftable_items: { gift_type: 'ticket' })
                         ^
```

**Update:** With a select:

```
Gift.joins(:giftable_items)
    .where(giftable_items: { gift_type: 'ticket' })
    .select(['total_value', 'gifts.created_at', 'user_id'])
```

Comment: This is making `inner join`, but the `where` clause is now pretty cool. Any ideas how to make the `select` to be something like `select(gifts: [:total_value, :created_at, :user_id])`?

Comment: You don't need to select the attributes, you can just leave it like it is and use only the attributes you want. -- Actually I found a way to do it, see my updated answer @hrvladev

Comment: This is not working, because the field **created_at** is in the both tables. So Rails will tell you that it is **ambiguous**. And I need to select them, because I don't need the other fields loaded in memory.

Thanks for the help, though (: It's more readable now.

Comment: You're right, you can actually use the syntax you proposed: `select(gifts: [:total_value, :created_at, :user_id])`

Comment: Pfff my bad I didn't test it properly, you can use: `.select([:total_value, 'gifts.created_at', :user_id])`

Comment: I was using that, but it's not consistent :D I mean I didn't like that there were symbols and string in the array. I guess I will just fallback to it again.

Comment: I understand, but you don't really need to select those attributes since they belong to the Gift object, and they will all be returned if you don't use a select

Comment: If I use select the returned object will have only the selected fields as properties and the memory used will be less. And if you try to access other property of the object (say defined in the model) there will be an error.

Comment: I understand that, but selecting all of them would avoid the pure SQL problem in the query, and maybe its trivial to select only 3 attributes for performances purposes. Meh, all of this depends on the Gift's number of attributes.